# Downloading a live Twitch stream

Tags: video-streaming, twitch

I'm looking for a way to "pipe" (sorry if I'm butchering the terminology here) a Twitch stream into a file as it is being streamed. I know it is possible to download the VODs after the stream is done but that is not applicable in my use case.

Ive had a look at a library called [streamlink](https://github.com/streamlink/streamlink) which would allow me to get the exact url of a given stream but I'm kind of lost as to where to go from here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution that worked for me:

Firstly, install [Streamlink](https://streamlink.github.io/). Then just run this command

`streamlink -o <file name>.mkv <URL of the Twitch stream> best`

to save the stream to local file.

If you want to achieve this programmatically you can use the Streamlink pip module (`pip 
 install streamlink`) in conjuction with [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).

Here's what the code might look like (in Python 3):

```py
import streamlink
from subprocess import Popen
from time import sleep

# get the URL of .m3u8 file that represents the stream
stream_url = streamlink.streams('https://www.twitch.tv/forsen')['best'].url
print(stream_url)

# now we start a new subprocess that runs ffmpeg and downloads the stream
ffmpeg_process = Popen(["ffmpeg", "-i", stream_url, "-c", "copy", 'stream.mkv'])

# we wait 60 seconds
sleep(60)

# terminate the process, we now have ~1 minute video of the stream
ffmpeg_process.kill()
```

Answer (score 6):

youtube-dl provides an interface for obtaining the playlist from a stream URL. The below 1 liner works well:

`ffmpeg -i $( youtube-dl -f best --get-url twitch.tv/host ) -codec copy "out.mp4"`

There is also a [twitch-dl](https://github.com/ihabunek/twitch-dl/) utility I have not tried.

Answer (score 0):

youtube-dl is deprecated. But [it's fork yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/releases) can download almost any unprotected video. (you'll need installed ffmpeg or just .exe in the same folder).
Windows users can make .bat file with code below and run it to save any stream, (including not yet live one), if the stream-url is known in advance.

There is one caveat: on twitch, you will have to experimentally determine at what sampling rate the streamer you need streams (default is 48kHz) and specify it correctly (otherwise there may be problems with audio). Thank [this guy](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtubedl/comments/wj65b9/twitch_streams_recorded_with_ytdlp_seem_to_be/) for the batch file.

```
@echo off 
echo TwitchRec 1.3
echo.
set /P twitchUrl="Enter Twitch URL:"
set /P audioOnly="Audio only(y/n):"
if /I "%audioOnly%"=="N" (set /P aRate="Set audio sample rate(48/44.1):")
if "%aRate%"=="48" (set aRate=48000)
if "%aRate%"=="44.1" (set aRate=44100)
if "%aRate%"=="" (set aRate=48000)


if /I "%audioOnly%"=="Y" (set /P format="Which audio format(mp3,aac,alac,flac,m4a,mp3,opus,vorbis,wav):")
:start
if /I "%audioOnly%"=="Y" (yt-dlp -o "%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" -x --audio-format %format% --ignore-config --fixup never %twitchUrl%)
if /I "%audioOnly%"=="N" (yt-dlp -o "%%(title)s" --ignore-config --fixup never %twitchUrl% --exec "ffmpeg -i {} -c:v copy -af asetrate=%aRate% {}_f.mp4 && del {}")
timeout 15
goto start
```